# How to write Test Cases?

Tags: c#, testing, testcase

I want to learn how to write test cases before writing the code. I read an article about test-driven development. I wonder how developers write test cases? For Example this method:

```
    public int divideNumbers(int num1, int num2)
    {
      return num1 / num2;
    }
```

Comment: you know that you have already written the code before your tests? :)

Answer (score 4):

We start with a blank project now. You want to do something, say divide two numbers. So you write a test describing what you want to do:

```
Assert.That(divide(10,2), Eq(5))
```

This test gives you an entry point: it describes the acceptable interface of the `divide` method. So you proceed to implement it as `int divide(int x, int y)` for example.

Write tests that describe what you expect to get from your code. You don't need to think much about it. The most normal way of writing your expectation is probably the best way to design your code, and then you can implement it to satisfy your test.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps for testing. From `MSDN`;

- [Testing Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292191%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Unit Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292197%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Integration Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292128%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

In your case;

```
Assert.AreEqual(divideNumbers(8, 4), 2);
```

`Assert` class verifies conditions in unit tests using `true`/`false` propositions. You should write your test cases what you expecting their results. You can use `TestMethod` attribute for your test methods. There is a cool post about [Creating Unit tests for your c# code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391465/Creating-Unit-tests-for-your-csharp-code). Analyze it very well.

Comment: Actually what I want to ask has an answer that the link you shared from codeproject. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a stub of the function/class/component that you want to develop. It should compile, but deliberately not (yet) do what it is supposed to do.

For example:

```
public int divideNumbers(int num1, int num2)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

or

```
    return -42;
```

Think about the intended behavior, treating the stub as an interface to a black box. Don't care about the implementation (yet). Think about the "contract" of the interface: X goes in, Y goes out.

Identify standard cases and important egde cases. Write tests for them.

For integer division (assuming we would write it from scratch) there are actually quite a couple of cases to consider: With and without remainder, n/1, n/0, 0/n, 0/0, negative numbers, etc.

```
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(4,4) == 1);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(4,3) == 1);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(4,2) == 2);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(4,1) == 4);
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => divideNumbers(4,0));

Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(0,4) == 0);
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => divideNumbers(0,0));

Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers( 4,-2) == -2);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(-4, 2) == -2);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(-4,-2) ==  2);

Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers( 4,-3) == -1);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(-4, 3) == -1);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(-4,-3) ==  1);
```

Compile and run the unit tests. Do they all fail? If not, why? Maybe one of the tests is not working as intended (tests can be buggy, too!).

Now, start to implement until no test fails anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Start by realizing the difference between theory and practice.

Any real life system will have stuff that is easily created via TDD and some that are not.

The last group is everything dependent on environment, when working on a system that does not seek to abstract away environmental assumptions, but pragmatically accept these.

This group can be developed in a TDD fashion, but it will require additional tooling and extensions to the software factory.

For .Net this would be tooling and extensions such as MS virtual Test Lab and SpecFlow.

What I am trying to communicate is that **it depends**.

For very simple component/unit testing, the idea would be to write a failing testcase, before writing the code to be tested, and ending development when test runs successfully.

For integration testing and beyond (system testing), you will need to consider, among other things, how to bring the test environment into some known state in addition to considering what to test for.